# TextView selection, event for the moment when selection is done?

Tags: android, textview, android-widget, android-menu

How can I get notified at the moment when the selection menu appears for `TextView`?

See the screen recording below. If you select some text, context menu (copy/share/select all) appears. If you begin to drag the blue drag handle, the context menu disappears, and once you release the handle, the menu appears again. So, basically, the menu appears only when selection is done, not whilst you are still selecting the text.

I want to get notified when selection is done (i.e., the same time as the menu appears). I thought that `onPrepareActionMode` would be called when the selection is done and the menu appears, but after testing with the code below, it seemed that  `onPrepareActionMode` is continuously called whilst I am dragging the handle, even when the selection menu is not visible. Also, it often got called twice for a single dragging. So `onPrepareActionMode` does not seem to be then answer. Then what is?

[image]

```
    object: ActionMode.Callback{
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean
        {
            Log.d("test", "onCreateActionMode");
            return true;
        }

        override fun onPrepareActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean
        {
            Log.d("test", "onPrepareActionMode");
            return false
        }

        override fun onActionItemClicked(mode: ActionMode?, item: MenuItem?): Boolean
        {
            Log.d("test", "onActionItemClicked");
            return false;
        }

        override fun onDestroyActionMode(mode: ActionMode?)
        {
            Log.d("test", "onDestroyActionMode");
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

No answer? I thought that this would be a common requirement to do something automatically when text is selected. Anyway, I spent a lot of time trying to find a way and it all failed. But the hint came from a random thing: I have noticed that whenever the text selection is done and the menu appears,

> W/androidtc: TextClassifier called on main thread

is printed in the Logcat. That is how I found that there is `TextClassifier` in `TextView`. So, I tried the following code

```
    val tc = object:TextClassifier{
        override fun classifyText(request: TextClassification.Request): TextClassification
        {
            Log.d("test", "classifyText")
            return super.classifyText(request)
        }
    }

    text2.setTextClassifier(tc);
```

, and as I suspected, `classifyText` was called when the selection is done, not during I was dragging the selection handle. This is also called when the selection is closed (tap elsewhere), but I guess I can probably filter that out by checking if the selected text length is 0. I will use this workaround until someone who knows better posts a more elegant and correct solution.

---

PS: The code above works on Android 10/11/12, but caused a runtime exception on Android 8.1. I guess that it is because there are no default implementations for methods on Android 8.1.

For Android 8.1, I have tried the following and it worked. If you do not care about classifier itself, I guess you do not have to pass the default classifier and use the commented-out dummy return values.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val textClassificationManager = getSystemService(Context.TEXT_CLASSIFICATION_SERVICE) as TextClassificationManager;
    val defaultOne = textClassificationManager.textClassifier;
    val txt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview1);
    txt.setTextClassifier(MyTextClassfier(defaultOne));
}

inner class MyTextClassfier(private val fallback:TextClassifier) : TextClassifier by fallback
{
    override fun suggestSelection(
        text: CharSequence,
        selectionStartIndex: Int,
        selectionEndIndex: Int,
        defaultLocales: LocaleList?
    ): TextSelection
    {
        return fallback.suggestSelection(text, selectionStartIndex, selectionEndIndex, defaultLocales);
        //return TextSelection.Builder(selectionStartIndex, request.getEndIndex()).build();
    }

    override fun classifyText(
        text: CharSequence,
        startIndex: Int,
        endIndex: Int,
        defaultLocales: LocaleList?
    ): TextClassification
    {
        //Selection ended. User has lifted his finger.
        return fallback.classifyText(text, startIndex, endIndex, defaultLocales);
        //return TextClassification.Builder().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Works ✅

Comment: @SenocicoStelian Check the added code, if you want this to work on Android 8.1. It seems that the `TextClassifer` class was added on Android 8.0, so I am not sure how I can get it work before Android 8.0.

Comment: @DamnVegetables have you tested this in the wild? Does it work on all devices above android 8.1?